# Haskell count occurrences in two dimensional lists

Tags: list, haskell, count, 2d

I have to count the occurrences in a two dimensional (2D) list [[Int]], but I get errors.

What I tried so for is counting 1D. It works fine like this:

```
instances::Int->[Int]->Int
instances x [] = 0
instances x (y:ys)
    | x==y = 1+(instances x ys)
    | otherwise = instances x ys
```

Could you please help me to modify this function in order to count a 2D list:

```
instances::Int->[Int]->Int
```

Thanks in advance
Greetings

Answer (score 3):

```
instances2D x = length . filter (==x) . concat
```

or

```
instances2D y xss = sum [1 | xs <- xss, x <- xs, y == x]
```

Comment: thanks, I'm trying it and I'll give you feedback about it in a moment.

Comment: but `instances2D x = length . filter (==x) . concat`. won't work, since length counts each character, therefore it will work jut for 0 to 9. If you put more than one digit for a number, then it will count each digit as one occurrence

Comment: however I could divide it by it self, so that I get for each element 1 and get the length of that, right?

Comment: I take it all back – length works. I thought it would count every digit as string... sorry

Comment: @John `lenght` counts every element of a sequence. If you pass a `String` it will count every `Char`, because `String` is conceptually `[Char]`. `lenght`'s signature is `[a] -> Int` meaning that `length` doesn't care about the type of the element on the list.

Answer (score 0):

With your *explicit recursion* (v. a library function that hides the recursion), all you need is a function that can step through the elements of your 2D list.  If you can write a function that steps through each element of your 2D list and gets each sub-list into a variable, then you can call your 1D function on that variable.  And stepping through the elements of any list is easy with pattern matching:

```
matchesIn2DList:: Int -> [[Int]] -> Int
matchesIn2DList _ [] = 0   --> [] is an empty 2D list
matchesIn2DList x (l:ls) =    
    (matchesIn1DList x l) + (matchesIn2DList x ls)
```

Note that in the your base case:

```
instances x [] = 0
```

the value being searched for is immaterial: the count for the matches in an empty list will always be 0 no matter what value you are searching for, so you can use _ instead of a variable name.